# How to compare sales of 2 different time periods?

Tags: powerbi

I have 2018 and 2019 sales datas stored weekly. 
For example, first week of 2019: 140.000 $
second week of 2019: 135.000$
.
.
.
first week of 2018: 110.000 $
second week of 2018: 113.000$
.

It goes in the same fashion.I want to compare weekly sales of these 2 years in a graph. I will choose some of the weeks of 2019 ( ex: 3,5,6,12 and 13. weeks) and choose some of the weeks from 2018 ( ex: 7,8 and 10. weeks) and compare sales of this 2 years. 
As I am a learner currently, I could not do it. If you can help me, I would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a date hierarchy on the Axis at a bar chart (Year, Quarter, Month, Week). The value would be the sum of your sales. Now if you add a filter visual with the weeks you can filter and compare like you need it. The filter visual should just include the `KW xx` without the year otherwise you will filter for `2019 KW xx` and you cant compare.

[image]